# Magento 2: Regenerate categories URL rewrites

Tags: magento2, category, url

Can somebody tell me how can i regenerate category URLS in magento 2?

I did not found any solution or module, that can help me.

[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/how-to-delete-and-regenerate-url-rewrites-in-magento-2/166507) i found module, that regenerate URLs for products and it's work fine, but i need to regenerate category urls.

So, can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try reindexing ?

Answer (score 2):

Extension [IndexerUrlRewrite](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.IndexerUrlRewrite) regenerate product urls, category urls and cms page urls.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is, do everything by hand in the

Marketing > URL Rewrite section and select on the left top drop down

> Create URL Rewrite: for category

Very tiring procedure  when you have like 500 categories and subcategories

Answer (score 0):

You can use my extension:
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

It regenerate Url Rewrites for products and for categories.