# Inquiry regarding url_path product attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, url

Product has an attribute called **url_path**.

- What is the purpose of this attribute ?
- When does it get populated with values ?
- When are this values used ?

Answer (score 0):

Product attribute **url_path** will be a concatenation of **url_key**  and the **Product URL Suffix** defined under **System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization**.

If the same url_key already exists, it will also ensure that you don't have duplicate **url_path** by suffixing your **url_key** with an hyphen and the product's **entity_id**.

Comment: I believe that will be the url_key attribute.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I've just updated my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank for your time and your answer.
So i'm changing the product url key from product edit (admin).
There is basically no value being populated for the url_path attribute.
I can't seem to find a scenario in which the url_path attribute is populated.

Comment: Have you reindex your product URL rewrites after your edits?

Comment: Magento 2 does not have native product url rewrites reindex.

Comment: Maybe you need to regenerate your products URLs,  take a look at this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/how-to-delete-and-regenerate-url-rewrites-in-magento-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa