# Magento2.2 sitemap genrate after some product url not showing properly

Tags: magento2.2, url-rewrite, product-urls, sitemaps

I have to used Magento2.2 and we are also install in our site this plugin olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites but we are truncate url_rewite table after run this command on our staging site than after flush and reindex sitemap.xml inside getting url

```
http://test.XXX-italy.com/catalog/product/view/id/86
```

Please if any one know how to resolve it url for sitemap already i used this plugin  OlegKoval RegenerateUrlRewrites but when i regenrate after check it sitemap.xml there  this type "http://test.XXX-italy.com/catalog/product/view/id/86" of more than url  showing it.

Comment: can you please check directly, its loading via normal url.

Comment: i think its url_rewrite issue.

Comment: I know but in sitemap some url getting wrong i use plugin and run it but not regenrate

Comment: first, try this step - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/how-to-delete-and-regenerate-url-rewrites-in-magento-2

Comment: already i have to check it please what are you say to explain brief

Comment: First please load this url in address bar.

Comment: this url open it product like put in our browser http://test.XXX-italy.com/catalog/product/view/id/86

Comment: But actually i facing it our sitemap.xml inside this url genrated i apply regenrated module and truncate it url_rewite table but not getting correct url

Comment: Try with admin side product list mass action to select product and update with website.