# Magento2.3.0 : In admin inside Payment method after save getting error

Tags: error, magento2.3, payment-methods, admin-panel, save

I am using `Magento 2.3.0` I go to admin panel

> store -> configuration -> sales -> payment methods

enable any payment method after save below image display.

[image]
on this same page showing this error screenshot attached below

[image]

If any one idea please reply me how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you check your error.log?

Comment: I already check it error log but there not getting it

Comment: i suggest to you please clear cache or once logout and than login.

Comment: Issue Resolve it but not it proper solution u said "i suggest to you please clear cache or once logout and than login."

Comment: Is this been resolved or not?

Comment: Yes resolved it

Comment: I need other help to url regenrator "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280441/magento2-2-sitemap-genrate-after-some-product-url-not-showing-properly?noredirect=1#comment400934_280441"