# Magento2 Optimize url_rewrite table

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

We have recently migrated Magento1 to Magento2.we found that url_rewrite table has almost 16000000+ rows.
M1 site was build before 6 years and the url rewrite table has increased over the years.
This website has around 6000+ categories and 8000+ products.

Is there a good article or process that we can optimize this table to increase the performance.
We want to make sure we do not lose any SEO URLs.

Thank you

Comment: Hey, backup the database, if you keep categories and products names the same it will generate them with the same paths, try delete them all and generate them again so you stay only with the ones needed and not lots of ones magento don't even use. To generate we usually use https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites but there is other options. I don't think there is any way to optimize it better than delete all the unneeded entries. Make sure you backup that table at least in case something goes wrong. Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 1):

Take backup of site first

Open phpmyadmin and search for url rewrite table
and truncate it ( Please make sure you have uncheck foreign key checkbox )

Then install extension follow instruction to remove all unnecessary rewrite which is not useful

Please follow this link
https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

For more info
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/166507/77554

Happy coding